# Why my optional:true option is not working in my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, migration, belongs-to

I am struggling with the following migration:

```
class CreatePartnerActivationHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :partner_activation_histories do |t|
      t.references :partner, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :owner, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: 'admin_users' }
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class PartnerActivationHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "AdminUser", optional: true
end
```

When I try to create a `PartnerActivationHistory` record without an owner, it raises the following error:

`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "owner_id" of relation "partner_activation_histories" violates not-null constraint`

I can't figure it out why my `optional: true` is not working...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not a Rails programmer myself, but null: false smells like NOT NULL constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An optional owner would mean an `owner_id` of `nil`/`NULL` in the database, but your spec for that column says it is mandatory and can't be `null`.

Remove the non-null requirement from the column like this and you should be good:

```
class CreatePartnerActivationHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :partner_activation_histories do |t|
      t.references :partner, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :owner,                foreign_key: { to_table: 'admin_users' }
  end
end
```

You'll want to rollback your current migration, make the change to the migration file, then migrate forward again. Assuming you're okay with losing all of the current `PartnerActivationHistory` records. If not, you'll need to make a new migration that just modifies that one column by removing the non-null constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was focused on my model page and not especially on the migration. Removed `null: false` resolved my problem!